# If $a \in \mathbb{I}$ , how is $\overline{\mathbb{Z}+ a\mathbb{Z}}=\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

If $a \in \mathbb{I}$ , how is $$\overline{\mathbb{Z}+ a\mathbb{Z}}=\mathbb{R}$$

It says in my notebook that this set in dense in $\mathbb{R}.$ How do I prove this density? With say $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{I}$ being dense in $\mathbb{R}$ I thought it was dense because every point in $\mathbb{R}$ was either in $\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{I})$ or a limit point of $\mathbb{Q}\text{ -being } \mathbb{I}(\mathbb{I}\text{ -being }\mathbb{Q}).$

Now here say $a\to \frac{1}{2}\in \mathbb{I}$, take example $b=\frac{1}{4}\in \mathbb{R}$ which I don't see as being a limit point of $\mathbb{Z}+ a\mathbb{Z}...$

Comment: this needs clarification....$\frac 12$ is rational, it's not in $\mathbb I$.

Comment: What I meant there is an irational number that is very close to $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: But, of course any irrational is very close to some rational.  I see what you are saying, but what you've written is not clear.

Comment: Could it be that a isn't fixed ?

Comment: The notation is confusing; I can't recall ever seeing $\mathbb{I}$ used for the irrationals before.  I was gong to edit to replace it with $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, or just the word 'irrational', but your second sentence tripped me up.  Perhaps try editing it yourself.

Comment: Irrationals by definition are arbitrarily close to rationals, they are defined as the completion of the rationals.

Comment: THis is what $\mathbb{Z}+ a\mathbb{Z}$ looks to me if I take an $a$ close to 1/2, lets denote this irrational as $1/2I$ that is very very close to 1/2: $\mathbb{Z}+ a\mathbb{Z}=\{...0.5I, 1, 1.5I, 2, 2.5I,3, 3.5I ...\}$ How is for example $b=1/4 \in \overline{\mathbb{Z}+ a\mathbb{Z}} ?? $ Im not seeing this

Comment: @BozoVulicevic...no, you are using $\frac 12$ again.  the "very close" bit you mentioned adds up if you multiply by big enough integers.

Comment: I understand what you mean there, but in this example how is $\frac{1}{4}\in  \overline{\mathbb{Z}+ a\mathbb{Z}}$

Comment: If i take a ball $(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{8}) \cap( \mathbb{Z}+ a\mathbb{Z}) = \emptyset $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key points:  Your set is closed under internal addition and subtraction (that is, if $x$ and $y$ are in your set then so is $x + y$ and $x - y$.  Further, your set is closed under multiplication by arbitrary integers (clearly).

Suppose that $0$ were a limit point of your set.  That means that given an arbitrarily small $\epsilon > 0$ I can find integers $\{m,n\}$ such that $|m+na| < \epsilon$.  But then look at the set of points $\{k(m+na) \;\; k \in \mathbb Z\}$. Clearly every real number $x$ is within $\epsilon$ of one of those.  In this way I see that every real number must be a limit point, so your set is dense.

Note, too, that if there are any limit points at all, then $0$ is a limit point (because if your set draws arbitrarily near some $x$ then differences between those elements, which are also in your set, draw arbitrarily near $0$).

Finally, then, we just need to consider the case in which there are no limit points at all.  But then I can find integers $\{m,n\}$ such that $m + na$ is the smallest positive element of your set.  It follows that every element of your set is of the form $\{k(m+na)\}$ for some integer $k$ since, otherwise, that element would fall in the gap between two multiples of your minimal element and I could construct a smaller element. The fact that $a$ is in your set means that $n$ can't be $0$ (as $a$ is not an integer) But $1$ is in your set so $1 = km + kna$ for integers $r$ and $s$, whence $a = \dfrac {1-km}{kn}$ so a would be rational, a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, can you formally prove that $0$ is indeed a limit point, directly ? :)

Comment: Because, after the second paragraph I cannot follow.

Comment: I think I have proven it formally.  I think you mean "can you prove it constructively"...that is to say "give an algorithm which generates an explicit sequence of my form which converges to $0$" and to that my answer is "Well..it depends what you mean."  Continued fractions give rational approximations to your number so if you can get the c.f. then you can say a lot.  Or, if your irrational is given as a value (or a root) of some familiar function then you can generally use that function to get a sequence (Taylor expansions or Newton's method often help).

Comment: Don't forget:  if you write out some ghastly expression like $e^
{\pi^2}-(\sqrt 2)^{\sqrt e}$ then it can be fantastically difficult even to determine whether or not the number is irrational.  That strongly suggests that there can't be an easy, algorithmic way to decide if your set is dense or not.

Comment: The logic of my argument is as follows:  Look at your set.  We want to know that, if $\alpha$ is irrational, then your set is dense.  Logically, we have three (exhaustive, but non-exclusive) cases:  Case I:  your set has no limit points, Case II: your set has some limit points.  Case III:  0 is a limit points.  Case I is exclusive of the other two, clearly.  I then show that A. Case III implies our desired result.  B. Case II implies Case III.  and C. Case I implies that $\alpha$ is rational (contradicting the assumption).

Comment: (citing)lulu:[case where 0 is supposed as limit point]-"But then look at the set of points {k(m+na)k∈Z}. Clearly every real number x is within ϵ of one of those."Could you maybe add more thoughts/details why this is? I find it difficult to believe because $a$ is fixed?

Comment: Fix any positive $\delta$ and look at the set $S(\delta)$ of multiples of $\delta$.  You'll agree, I trust, that every real number $r$ is within $\delta$ of some element of $S(\delta)$?  (Actually, every real number has to be within $\frac 12 \delta$ of an element of $S(\delta)$ but we didn't need that for our argument).  That's all I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

The notation should be interpreted as follows:
$$
\mathbb{Z} + a \mathbb{Z} = \{n + a m ~\vert~ n, m \in \mathbb{Z}\}
$$

So, given any real number $r \in \mathbb{R}$, and any $\epsilon > 0$, our task is to find $m, n$ such that
$$
|n + a m - r| < \epsilon
$$

Comment: How would I formally find these $n, m $ ??