# Question on complete metric spaces and whether the following is a complete metric space:

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

**Let   $ S \subset C^2([0,1])$(set of all two-times differentiable functions on $[0,1]$), which satisfy $$f(0)+f(\frac{1}{2})+f(1)=0.$$ Question :Is $ (S,d)$ is a complete metric space, where $d$ is defined as: $$d(f,g)=\sup_{x \in [0,1]}{|f(x)-g(x)|}+3\sup_{x \in [0,1]}{|f'(x)-g'(x)|}+2\sup_{x \in [0,1]}{|f''(x)-g''(x)|}$$**

My thoughts: I cant definitely prove that $d$ is a metric, and was thinking if I could prove that $(C^2([0,1]),d)$ is a complete metric space as well (which I don't know how) and also proving that the set satisfying  $f(0)+f(\frac{1}{2})+f(1)=0.$ is a closed subset, then the job would be done. I don't know how to do these things.

Comment: Do you know about norms, better even, seminorms?

Comment: I have not studied semi-norms. Norms are known to me.

Comment: Seminorms are quasi like norms, you just may have $\lVert x\rVert = 0$ even when $x\neq 0$. Can you show that $p_k \colon f \mapsto \sup\limits_{x\in [0,1]} \lvert f^{(k)}(x)\rvert$ is a seminorm for all pertinent $k$? Then let $\lVert f\rVert = p_0(f) + 3p_1(f) +2 p_2(f)$. That's a norm on $C^2([0,1])$. Your distance is $d(f,g) = \lVert f-g\rVert$.

Comment: pertinent $k$- an unclear term

Comment: [pertinent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pertinent): relevant, applicable, apposite. Something that pertains [to the matter under consideration] is pertinent.

Comment: I very much appreciate your input, but I don't understand how to finish the question with this information, as it stands.

Comment: Here is an answer to a similar question. Can this be built upon to solve this one? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379372/completeness-of-c20-1-with-under-a-specific-metric

Comment: You probably have seen a proof that $C([0,1])$ is complete under the supremum norm $\lVert f\rVert = \sup\limits_{x\in [0,1]} \lvert f(x)\rvert$. Some modification of that proof shows that $C^2([0,1])$ is complete under the norm given above.

Comment: Yes, you can use that. It's essentially the same. The factors here don't change anything substantial.

Comment: Just in that question an integral is used as a condition, but here, something different. Proving that this set is closed is the only left unclarity.

Comment: I was only considering of the completeness of $C^2$ in relation to that other question. To show that $S$ is complete, we then need to see it's a closed subspace. That means you need to see that $\varphi(f) = f(0) + f(1/2) + f(1)$ is continuous on $C^2$.

Comment: That must be continuous. But why is that a sufficient condition for closure I dont understand ?

Comment: What connection is there between continuous maps and closed sets?

Comment: That the inverse map of a closed set of a continuous function is closed.

Comment: I know no other.

Comment: It's preimage, or inverse image, not inverse map. A map $g\colon X \to Y$ between topological spaces is continuous if and only if for every closed $F\subset Y$ its preimage $g^{-1}(F)$ is closed. That's the thing. Now look at $S$. Can you see that it is defined as the preimage of a close subset of $\mathbb{R}$ under some map?

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you help me with finding $n,m \in Z$ such that $|n+ma-r|< \epsilon , \forall \epsilon > 0 $ a-irational , r-real. I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{Z} + a \mathbb{Z} = \{n + a m ~\vert~ n, m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and nobody can seem to answer it.

Comment: Link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370662/if-a-in-mathbbi-how-is-overline-mathbbz-a-mathbbz-mathbbr